# Value of this in React event handler

Tags: reactjs

For some reason the value of this is being lost in react event handler. Reading the docs I thought that react did some stuff here to make sure this was set to the correct value

The following doesn't work as I'd expect

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Observer extends React.Component {

    handleClick() {
        console.log(this); //logs undefined
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
        );
    }
}
```

But this does:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Observer extends React.Component {

    handleClick() {
        console.log(this); //logs Observer class instance
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
        );
    }
}
```

React and ES6 is new to me but this seems to not be the correct behaviour?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be correct behaviour? Does jsx obscure the function you are creating for `onClick` too much?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6. It wouldn't work in ES5 either.

Comment: @Bergi Accepted answer says otherwise. In ES5 you would be using [React.createClass](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createclass) and you wouldn't manually have to bind. So yes, this has everything to do with the OP using ES6 to create React components.

Comment: @StijndeWitt: That's frame-work specific, of course. One could write a (failing) ES5 constructor that would be equivalent to the ES6 `class` without `React.createClass`, and one could still use `React.createClass` in ES6.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but this exact issue is mentioned by Facebook itself as one of the things to pay attention to *when converting from React ES5 to React ES6* so to say it has nothing to do with ES6 is just weird. Also, yes it's framework specific, but this question is tagged `reactjs` and `react-jsx` for a reason. The question *is* framework specific. Last, Facebook recommends `React.createClass` only for ES5 and explicitly recommends against it's use for ES6.

Comment: This bit me too.  Very surprising difference in behavior.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is correct behavior for JavaScript and React if you use the new `class` syntax.

The [autobinding feature does not apply to ES6 classes](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html) in v0.13.0.

So you'll need to use:

```
 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click</button>
```

Or one of the other tricks:

```
export default class Observer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    /* ... */
  }
  render() {
      return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited your answer to clarify that autobinding continues to work with React.createClass in all versions of React.

Comment: Note that in the docs you link to also give another solution using ES7 class properties to create arrow function handlers, ex `handleClick = (e) => { }`, then no `bind` call is needed in the constructor or anywhere.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is good and I've used it a lot in ES6, but I just want to add another "more modern" solution we have with ES7 (mentioned in the [React component class auto-binding notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)): use arrow functions as [class properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties), then you don't need to bind or wrap your handler anywhere.

```
export default class Observer extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    /* ... */
  }
  render() {
      return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
  }
}
```

This is the simplest and cleanest solution yet!

Comment: Isn't `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}` more effecient? I believe it's almost the same as `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)` except that the latter is more double-typing.

Comment: My example doesn't use `.bind()`, it defines the fat arrow as a class property and simply passes it in the callback prop. I would think this is more efficient than defining an arrow function in every render of a callback prop, and is less typing, especially if you want to use the handler in multiple places in your render function.

Answer (score 11):

Like others have said, React doesn't autobind methods to the instance when using ES6 classes. That said, I would make habit of always using arrow functions in event handlers like: `onClick={e => this.handleClick()}`

Instead of: `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}`

This because it means that you can replace the handleClick method with a spy in a test, something you can't do when you use bind.

Comment: In your arrow example, the handleClick method does not get the DOM element as an argument unless you explicitly pass it right?

Comment: Right, it needs to be `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e.target)}` for the handleClick function to get the clicked element.