# React JS 'this' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below code

```
save: function() {
        var _this = this;

        console.log(this.refs.itemText)

        this.setState({isEditing : false}, 
            function() {
                console.log("Inside call back");
                console.log(_this.refs);
                console.log(_this.refs.itemText);
             }   
        );    
    },
```

but _this is not accessible inside the callback function. Is this a scope issue?

See demo [here](http://codepen.io/kiranvj/pen/qqRzOL)

Comment: Probably, but it depends. Can you please share the way and the place you are calling the `save` method?

Comment: @KaloyanKosev I have added the codepen demo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of this in React event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732015/value-of-this-in-react-event-handler)

Comment: @abhirathore2006 that's not the case, since @phpsessionid is using `React.createClass` syntax.

Comment: @phpsessionid thanks for the codepen, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code, everything is working fine. the problem is with your logic.

let me explain you whats going wrong.

1. when you are in edit mode,  your itemText is rendered so its available in refs so it shows correct console log.
2. when you save and change the state, it re-renders the form and since your state got changed, your input element is now hidden. hence it returns undefined when you try to access its refs.

i hope this will answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The correct place to work with refs is inside specific [React lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) e.g. ComponentDidMount, ComponentDidUpdate.

In your case, if you want to do something right after the state is changed, hook-up on the `componentDidUpdate` method (instead of using the `this.setState` callback).

Read more about [the cautions of working with refs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).