# createClass to Component class React Conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code in this format:

```
  const Test = React.createClass({
      tabIcons: [],
      propTypes: {
      ...
      },
      render() {
       return
       <View> ...</View>
     }
  })
```

> I am not sure how to convert the tabIcons into the new format

```
class Test extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
  ...
  }
 render () {
  return (
   <View> ...</View>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: You could do `tabIcons = []` like you did with proptypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `tabIcons` as class property in your constructor.

```
class Test extends Component {

 constructor(){
  this.tabIcons = [];
 }

 static propTypes = {
  ...
 }

 render () {
  return (
   <View> ...</View>
  )
 }
}
```

Now you can access it anywhere in the class similar to state.

```
this.tabIcons.push(newItem)
```

Comment: I get the error `undefined is not a object ( evaluating 'this.tabIcons.forEach')`  when I try to call `this.tabIcons.forEach((icon, i) => { })`

Comment: Where did you call this? Maybe you haven't set context correctly with `bind`.

Comment: take a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/jasan-s/64a47c3d237748b5a1b5171c9fed4b6f

Comment: bind this method to class context by putting this line inside your constructor.
`this.setAnimationValue  = this.setAnimationValue.bind(this) ;`

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara Actually, since React Native is bundled with Babel, a more convenient way would be to use `setAnimationValue = ({ value }) => { ... }`, a method as a class property, and to use `tabIcons = []` like they did with `propTypes`. That way no binding is necessary and no constructor is needed at all.

Comment: @jasan You're welcome. Take a look at this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732015/value-of-this-in-react-event-handler

Comment: @AndrewLi but then it's going to be a static property and will be common for every instance of the component right? So might be a problem if you have multiple instances of `Test`. I think that's why even react team chose to use this approach for `state` and static approach for prototypes.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara I never said it had to be static. Just a class property will be instance based.

Comment: @AndrewLi You said like did with proptypes. proptypes are static. That's why I thought so. Yes. As long as you use this babel transform http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/ you can define `tabIcons` as a class property.

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara What I meant by "like they did with proptypes" was it as a class property, not that it was static.