# React how to invoke a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to invoke a method on the component props before the page load. For testing I've created a button to invoke the method , but this is not what I desire , and I don't know how to change it so it will be called instantly when you reach this path .

My current code :

```
class BrokersList extends React.Component {
  getTableData = () => {
    this.props.getBrokerDetails()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.root}>
        <button 
                variant="outlined" 
                color="primary" 
                onClick={this.getTableData}></button>

          {this.props.details.length > 0 && <Table {...this.props}/>}
      </Paper>

    )
  }
}
```

I thought about calling the `getTableData` via the render method, but render should be pure so it didn't work . (`Table` component is being populated from the state that is being updated by this method)

Comment: There are some lifecycle hooks in react to load something before after the component load , you can go through it.

Comment: componentWillMount ? do I have access to the props via this lifecycle ?

Comment: You need to wrap you onClick in arrow function or use bind

Comment: Check [Value of this in React event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732015/value-of-this-in-react-event-handler)

Comment: @Yossi componentDidMount  will have the props as well state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use the `componentDidMount` life cycle method.

Here is example code of what may work for you.

```
class BrokersList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBrokerDetails()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.root}>
          {this.props.details.length > 0 && <Table {...this.props}/>}
      </Paper>

    )
  }
}
```

Now your call to `getBrokerDetails` will fire right after the first render of this component. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for more details on this life cycle method.

Comment: Thanks,I'll accept when possible. You have a typo btw (missing parenthesis)

Comment: It's also worth keeping in mind that until recently `componentWillMount` would have served your purposes as well. However, it is now deprecated, so be wary of any tutorials advocating its use.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass method to handler as is that use this it will be window object or undefined if used in strict mode:

```
class BrokersList extends React.Component {
  getTableData = () => {
    this.props.getBrokerDetails()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.root}>
        <button 
                variant="outlined" 
                color="primary" 
                onClick={() => this.getTableData()}></button>

          {this.props.details.length > 0 && <Table {...this.props}/>}
      </Paper>

    )
  }
}
```

or using `onClick={this.getTableData.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
class BrokersList extends React.Component {
  render () {
    // get method props
    const {getBrokerDetails} = this.props
    return (
      <Paper className={this.props.classes.root}>
        <button 
                variant="outlined" 
                color="primary" 
                onClick={getBrokerDetails}></button>
                {/* call the method ^^ */}

          {this.props.details.length > 0 && <Table {...this.props}/>}
      </Paper>

    )
  }
}
```