# Why doesn't this grab the text from my input? error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently very new to React. Trying to make a input box and when I type into the input box and click submit, an alert box pops up with the text that I typed.

```
      import React from "react";
      import "./App.css";

      class TodoListt extends React.Component {
        state = {};

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.input = React.createRef();
        }

        handleSubmit(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(this._inputElement.value);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input ref={a => (this._inputElement = a)} placeholder="...todo" />
                <button>submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default TodoListt;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property '_inputElement' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of this in React event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732015/value-of-this-in-react-event-handler)

Comment: there are many, many questions on Stack Overflow regarding undefined `this` inside of react event listener functions. which of them have you tried and why didn't they work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `handleSubmit` to an arrow function:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(this._inputElement.value);
}
```

[This](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/) is an excellent article on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      import React from "react";
      import "./App.css";

      class TodoListt extends React.Component {
        state = {};

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.input = React.createRef();
        }

        handleSubmit(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(this.input.current.value);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input ref={this.input} placeholder="...todo" />
                <button>submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      export default TodoListt;
```