# Push object from JSON rest api into empty array not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to push a object from a JSON response from a rest api into an empty array in React, so far my code is not working, I am fairly new to React so can't see where I am going wrong? Maybe something to do with the function in the state? I am getting error:

```
Cannot read property 'saved' of undefined
```

code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './news-hero.css';
import Carousel from "react-multi-carousel";
import "react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css";

const responsive = {
    superLargeDesktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
        items: 1,
    },
    desktop: {
        breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
        items: 1,
    },
    tablet: {
        breakpoint: { max: 1024, min: 464 },
        items: 1,
    },
    mobile: {
        breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
        items: 1,
    },
};

class NewsHero extends Component {
    state = {
        loading: false,
        data: [],
        headline: [],
        saved: []
    }

    saved() {
        this.saved.push(this.headline);
        //alert('this is saved kind of');
    }

    onError() {
        this.setState({
            imageUrl: "../assets/img-error.jpg"
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=timbaland&domains=rollingstone.com,billboard.com&excludeDomains=townsquare.media&apiKey=8')
            .then(headline => headline.json())
            .then(headline => this.setState({ headline: headline.articles, loading: false }, () => console.log(headline.articles)))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="hero">
                <h2 className="text-left">News</h2>

                {this.state.loading
                    ? "loading..."
                    : <div>
                        <Carousel
                            additionalTransfrom={0}
                            showDots={true}
                            arrows={true}
                            autoPlaySpeed={3000}
                            autoPlay={false}
                            centerMode={false}
                            className="carousel-hero"
                            containerClass="container-with-dots"
                            dotListClass="dots"
                            draggable
                            focusOnSelect={false}
                            infinite
                            itemClass="carousel-top"
                            keyBoardControl
                            minimumTouchDrag={80}
                            renderButtonGroupOutside={false}
                            renderDotsOutside
                            responsive={responsive}>
                            {this.state.headline.map((post, indx) => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="text-left mt-5" key={indx}>
                                        <img className="media-img card-img-top card-img-hero" src={post.urlToImage} alt="Alt text"></img>
                                            <div className="card-body container hero-text-body">
                                                <h1 className="card-title hero-title text-truncate">{post.title}</h1>
                                                <button className="btn-primary btn mt-2 mb-4" onClick={this.saved}>Add this article</button>
                                                <p className="card-text">{post.description}</p>
                                                <a href={post.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Read More</a>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                        </Carousel>

                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default NewsHero;
```

Any idea's and insight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of this in React event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732015/value-of-this-in-react-event-handler)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cannot read property 'saved' of undefined

You are not correctly referencing `this.state` for `saved` or `headline`.

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Either add a constructor and bind `this` to your `saved` function.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.saved = this.saved.bind(this);
}

saved() {
    this.saved.push(this.headline);
    //alert('this is saved kind of');
}
```

Or define `saved` as an arrow function to bind `this`

```
saved = () => {
    this.saved.push(this.headline);
    //alert('this is saved kind of');
}
```

Should be

```
saved() {
  const { headline, saved } = this.state;
  this.setState({ saved: [...saved, headline] });
}
```

or

```
saved = () => {
  const { headline, saved } = this.state;
  this.setState({ saved: [...saved, headline] });
}
```

**UPDATE:** Save a specific post/headline

I see now, if you wish to save a specific headline then you need to update the signature of your `saved` function **and** how you call it.

```
saved = headline => {
  this.setState(
    prevState => ({ saved: [...prevState.saved, headline] })
  );
}
```

and when you invoke it as a callback

```
<button
  className="btn-primary btn mt-2 mb-4"
  onClick={() => this.saved(post)} // pass the current post defined in the map callback
>
  Add this article
</button>
```

One minor comment about naming, consistently referencing the same "object" the same way throughout code *goes a long way* in helping readability. I.E. how you reference headlines, posts, and articles. Pick one and be consistent.

`this.state.headlines` => `this.state.headlines.map(headline => ...`

`this.state.posts` => `this.state.posts.map(post => ...`

`this.state.articles` => `this.state.articles.map(article => ...`

Comment: getting an error with that? Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: was missing a }

Comment: But even with that code Drew, getting the same error -  Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: My next guess then is that the `saved` function isn't correctly bound to `this`. Updating with binding suggestions.

Comment: Thanks that did work in a way, pushing to the empty array but when I console log it, It is pushing nothing on the first click of the saved() function but when I click save() again, it pushes all of the objects into the array not just the article I want, could this be something to do with the key index in the render() method?

Comment: No, it is/was how you use `saved` as a callback. I updated again.

Comment: Thanks Drew, but on your update for the Save a specific post/headline - on the click method you have (post), should that be (headline) or (headline.articles) based on the api call method? also the const saved method you have for this, where is that supposed to be placed in the code?

Comment: I believe it should be `post`. You saved `headline.articles` to `this.state.headline`, then you map your `headline` as so, `this.state.headline.map((post, idx) => ...` so at this point each element of the `headline` array is stored in a variable named `post` within the `map` callback. This is assuming you are actually trying to save one individual "headline" item/post/article (as the button text state).

Comment: Where would the `const saved = headline =>` be placed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206220/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-sole).

Answer (score 2):

```js
    saved() {
        this.saved.push(this.headline);
        //alert('this is saved kind of');
    }
```

You cannot defined class methods like this without writing a constructor like this:

```js
class NewsHero extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.saved = this.saved.bind(this)

  }

...the rest of everything you wrote

}
```

Without doing this, your `saved` function is not bound to the instance of the class.  Its silly, yes, but that's how class methods work in javasript.  The other option is to use an arrow function, which preserves the context if `this`:

```js
    saved = () => {
        this.saved.push(this.headline);
        //alert('this is saved kind of');
    }
```

I think this is faster and cleaner, and its pretty commonly used.

That is problem 1.  Problem 2 is that it appears you are trying to modify the state object directly when writing `this.saved.push(this.headline)`.  That's not how to do it.  To modify your state, you need to use the `this.setState` function:

```js
saved = () => {
  this.setState({
    saved: whatever you want this to be
  })
}
```

But it looks like you are already setting your state correctly in your fetch call, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your `saved` function...?

Comment: So the saved() function should add that specific article to the saved array, which are JSON objects in the rest api call.